# Qt. Изменение цвета кнопки на заданный цвет

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qss

Считываю цвет с помощью виджета lineEdit

```
QString color = ui->color_line->text();
```

Дальше нужно поменять цвет кнопки. Делаю как-то так

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton#Result { background-color:  }");
```

и вопрос, что прописать в background-color чтобы задать считанный цвет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QString color = ...;

QString style = QString("QPushButton#Result { background-color: %1 }").arg(color);

qApp->setStyleSheet(style);
```

Или непосредственно для кнопки:

```
btn->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: %1").arg(color));
```

Comment: Спасибо) а если будет background-color и еще какое-то поле, например: background-color: %1; поле: %2, как задать значения %1 и %2?

Comment: @Nedaxses  .arg(...).arg(...), или   .arg(v1,v2,...)  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html